# Rearange XML nodes XSL-T / variable?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have tried to rearange XML-Data with the structure:

```
<Root>
  <List_X>
    <Value>1</Value>
     ...
  </List_X>
  <List_Y>
    <Value>1</Value>
     ...
  </List_Y>
</Root>
```

to something like:

```
<Root>
  <List>
    <Value>
      <X>1</X>
      <Y>1</Y>
    </Value>
    ...
  </List_Y>
</Root>
```

My try was something like this

```
<for-each select="List_X/*">
  <variable name="pos" select="position()">
  <Value>
    <Test>
      <value-of select="$pos"/>
    </Test>
    <X>
      <value-of select="."/>
    </X>
    <y>
      <value-of select="../../List_Y/Value[$pos]/."/>
    </y>
  </Value>
</for-each>
```

Only problem as soon as i use pos in the  part it stopps changing (in Test), and sometimes the system just selects all Value nodes.

If i set a fixed value instead of $pos (or a variable eit a fixed value) everithing is fine.

Ps: the datastructure is generated from a Qt QObject (from the propertys usen SimpleXmlModdel ecpossing teo list proppertys).
The changed elements are needed for a Qt Quick XmlTableModell.

EDIT: Code:

:/xm.xml

```
<Root>
<List_X>
    <Value>1</Value>
    <Value>2</Value>
    <Value>3</Value>
    <Value>4</Value>
</List_X>
<List_Y>
    <Value>0.1</Value>
    <Value>0.2</Value>
    <Value>0.3</Value>
    <Value>0.4</Value>
</List_Y>
```

:/xsl.xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<ROOT>
<xsl:for-each select="Root/List_X/*">
<Value>
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="./position()"/>
<Test>
<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>
</Test>
<X>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</X>
<Y>
<xsl:value-of select="../../List_Y/*[$pos]"/>
</Y>
</Value>
</xsl:for-each>
</ROOT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QBuffer>
#include <QFile>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QXmlFormatter>
#include <QXmlQuery>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QByteArray xml,xsl,out;

    {
        QFile f(":/xm.xml");
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        xml = f.readAll();
    }
    ui->textEdit->setText(xml);
    {
        QFile f(":/xsl.xsl");
        f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        xsl = f.readAll();
    }
    ui->textEdit_2->setText(xsl);


    QXmlQuery query(QXmlQuery::XSLT20);
    query.setFocus(xml);
    query.setQuery(xsl);
    QBuffer b(&out);
    b.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QXmlFormatter serializer(query, &b);
    query.evaluateTo(&serializer);

    ui->textEdit_3->setText(out);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: "*sometimes the system just selects all Value nodes*" Please post a **reproducible** example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: At the moment i cant reproduce that.
Somehow nor even using * for all elements.

I add the Qt programm above.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce it anymore, then it sounds to me that your problem is solved. Unless you find a way to bring back the issue (reproducible, that is, otherwise there is no way we can help you), you can consider closing / answering / deleting your own question.

Comment: My main problem is that the variable stops changing, as soon as i use it in the select.
I found a way around it which i will post schortly (As awnser or edit, depending on what i am currently allowed to post.)

Answer (score 0):

The following changed xsl code performs as i want it to.
(Better solutions are allways wellkome)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="tmplate">
<Value>
<xsl:variable name="posi" select="position()"/>
<Test>
<xsl:value-of select="$posi"/>
</Test>
<X>
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</X>
<Y>
<xsl:value-of select="../../List_Y/Value[$posi]"/>
</Y>
</Value>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
<ROOT>
<xsl:for-each select="Root/List_X/Value">
<xsl:call-template name="tmplate"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</ROOT>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ROOT>
    <Value>
        <Test>1</Test>
        <X>1</X>
        <Y>0.1</Y>
    </Value>
    <Value>
        <Test>2</Test>
        <X>2</X>
        <Y>0.2</Y>
    </Value>
    <Value>
        <Test>3</Test>
        <X>3</X>
        <Y>0.3</Y>
    </Value>
    <Value>
        <Test>4</Test>
        <X>4</X>
        <Y>0.4</Y>
    </Value>
</ROOT>
```

Which might then be used in a Qt XmlTableModell with X and Y for the columns.

Comment: Functionally, I see no difference between this and your original code. -- P.S. `<xsl:for-each select="some-node"><xsl:call-template name="xyz"/>` can be simplified to `<xsl:apply-templates select="some-node"/>` and changing the named template to a template matching `some-node`.

Comment: apply-templates is a good hint. (I am relatively new to XSL, and my expirience with XML is mostly as DOM in a programm.)